# Remove Column Names From LINQ Resultset

Tags: jquery, json, linq, datatable

Don't know if my question is right or my plan is right, but i am using `jquery` datatable plugin and getting its `datasource` from a `Json` converted `LINQ` result.

My problem was, my resultset includes the name of the columns from my datatable(ado) which I think Jquery DataTable(client) does not require.

Is it possible if i dont include or rather remove the column names from my LINQ result before converting it to json?

Here is my server code.

```
 context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
 var y = from t in dt select t;
 ret = JsonConvert.SerializeObect(y, Formatting.None);

 context.Response.Write(ret);
```

The above code returns a result including all column names. Also i am using JSON.NET

Here is how i populate my dt

```
dsTableAdapters.dtTableAdapter adap = new dsTableAdapters.dtTableAdapter();
adap.Fill(ds.dt);
```

Output JSON:

```
[
[
    "COL1": 1,
    "COL2": "R1C2"
},
{
    "COL1: 2,
    "COL2": "R2C2"
},
{
    "COL1": 3,
    "COL2": "R3C3"
}
]
```

The required output based from jquery Datatable plugin must be:

```
[
[
    1,
    "R1C2"
],
[
    2,
    "R2C2"
],
[
    3,
    "R3C3"
]
]
```

Comment: but how do you give the column name of the table for the data?

Comment: dont know if i understand your question but i just do LINQ FROM T IN DT SELECT NEW { T.COL1, T.COL2 } then convert to json

Comment: Please post the code where you a) load the data via linq and convert it to json and b) where you consume the json on client side with the datatable.

Comment: database and datatable both are different thing... jquery is javascript framework, json is standard data structure for transport data btw two entities

Comment: Sorry for the delay. here is my server code.

Comment: How are you populating `dt` (show us code), and what do you expect to see in JSON (show us an example of the JSON that you want)?

Answer (score 0):

```
var y = (from t in dt.AsEnumerable() 
         select new { COL1= t.Field<string>("FirstName"), 
                      COL2 = t.Field<string>("LastName") }).ToList();
```

Assumming dt is your DataTable and  you have 2 columns called FirstName and LastName in your in that  and you want to output only those.

This will work. Tested.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx

The `AsEnumerable` extension method on a DataTable will return a Collection of DataRows. then you do a projection from your Linq Result with required fields. Since it is dataRow type, you need to specify what each column type will be.

Comment: Thanks you Shyju, but i already tried that code and the result is the same.

I think that will work if i include only 1 column.

        var y = (from t in dt select t.FirstName).ToList();

Comment: use only those columns you want to output in the select part

Comment: the result is still the same, still with column names.

Comment: really appreciate it., but after converting it to JSON. still has column names.

Comment: Here is the output after JSON.
    
    [
    {
        "name": 22,
        "lname": "Auger Initial Processing - IP Dry Oil Separator MBD-125 Liquid Outlet"
    },
    {
        "name": 23,
        "lname": "Auger Initial Processing - IP Dry Oil Separator MBD-125 Liquid Outlet"
    },
    {
        "name": 24,
        "lname": "Auger Initial Processing - IP Dry Oil Separator MBD-125 Liquid Outlet"
    },
    {
        "name": 1,
        "lname": "Auger Initial Processing - IP Dry Oil Separator MBD-125 Liquid Outlet"
    }
]

Comment: Still no luck, Maybe the only way, is to manually iterate through the resultset and append only the values to a stringbuilder type upon conversion to json?

Comment: @user1215811 change `name` and `lname` with `COL1` and `COL2` in the linq expression